# How can I upload video on Youtube and pause or resume it?

Tags: youtube, upload

I need a software, an Youtube Uploader for Ubuntu. I need to pause and resume the uploading when I want. Sorry for my English but I'm italian!

Comment: GJ, What do you mean by "Web uploader inside chrome or firefox" ? Is there a build-in chrome feature for uploading ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use the web uploader inside Chrome or Firefox - it has auto-resuming capability so that you can disconnect your Internet connection to pause the upload and then reconnect when you wish to continue the upload.

If you want to avoid losing Internet access from other programs, just change temporarily the browser's network settings to e.g. some non-existent proxy. This will kill connectivity just in the browser.

If you need browser access, either start the uploading in a separate/dedicated browser, or use some browser extension that let's you set proxy settings on a per-tab basis.

Answer (score 3):

I pause my uploads all the time. With the browser still open, put your computer to sleep. All of your other devices will have full connection speed. Then just wake your computer back up and the upload will resume.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, no, you can't pause your upload. If the server is not receiving data within a specific time then the upload will be aborted.

However, I've been using YouTube for a long time, and there's no third party program that can pause and resume uploading videos, you may want to convert your videos to a smaller file size.

To convert videos you can use Transmageddon.  You can install it fro USC.

[image]

Also take a look at [HandBrake](http://handbrake.fr/).

Comment: Uhm, I can try. How can i convert my videos to a smaller file size?

Comment: But why would you want to make it a smaller file size? In most cases that just means loss of quality.

Answer (score 1):

You can cancel upload,and then next you upload same file,it will resume last time you canceled.Here,upload something you don't need and then cancel,and upload same file again.Its going to resume.

That is how you pause/resume video uploading.But they should notice others about this that resumes next time you upload same thing.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

"Unfortunately, no, you can't pause your upload."

You can pause an upload by using youtube uploader which has a bandwidth limitters, pausing upload would be similar to limiting upload bandwidth to like 0.1 mbps or 0.01, something that would be enough for them not to drop communication and for you to feel like its not uploading anything. COnsider finding a program that has those limiting option, if you don't its easily coded by using google search.